# Why can't I step into or set a breakpoint in my XCode source?

Tags: iphone, xcode, compilation

I have several source files (all in one Group) that seem to compile with the project, but I cannot step into them or set any breakpoints within.

These files are newer versions of the same files I had in my project.  (I updated the code I am using from a 3rd party).  After the update, these newer files seem to compile with the project, but somehow they don't seem to be the ones the linker is putting in my final object (its like its using the older files).

So I can do this:
1. forcibly create a syntax error in one of these file and the compiler complains

I cannot do this:
1. hit a breakpoint in any of these files
2. step into any code in these files from a breakpoint outside
3. add a NSLog statement and see the output

Its like the project file (or something else) has its hand on the old compiled files (hence the project compiles fine and runs) and won't replace with these files.

help!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens that the new version gets put in some unexpected place and that you indeed have two versions of the file in your project without noticing.

Do a project wide search of some unique content in the old and new files. You should get both files displayed and you can delete the old one.

Comment: tried that, there is only 1 file.  is there some cached .o files?

Comment: Yes, perhaps also do a full "clean". (Cmd-shift-K).

Answer (score 0):

Are you running in release mode? Breakpoints and NSLog statements don't execute when you build and run in release mode.

Set your Active Build Configuration to Debug.

Comment: No I see plenty of NSLog output, just not the new ones I added.  I am running in debug mode.

Comment: Silly question, but did you clean your project after replacing the source files? (Product>>Clean)

Comment: hi, trying to now answer my own question, but my reputation doesn't allow it.

Comment: ok my apologies to all; i figured it out.

it had nothing to do with replacing files. the code was not being called because the linker was picking another method.

two days prior i integrated the BugSense-iOS.framework and upon inspecting their header files I see they define this:

@interface UIImageView (AFNetworking)

(void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage;
well the code i replaced also contained this. and now it appeared as if i wasn't being called. in reality i hasn't been called in days!

sorry all.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer, and then accept the answer.